# How to insert multiple rows including checkboxes and input fields

Tags: php, netbeans

I have a table of readonly input fields and a checkbox, for each how could I insert the checked boxes with the input fields related to them in my php code? multiple checkboxes at once?

Answer (score 1):

The key to resolve this issue is the name convention of inputs on the form.
If you have read-only inputs I will submit this without name attribute of inputs -
you need this only for presentation(correct me if I'm wrong). I will
only add names to the checkboxes -

```
<input type="checkbox" name="bikes[id]">
```

where id is the primary key from your database (eg. 23 as in below
example) and find record after submit by id. Your post array will be
included array with selected values - $_POST[bikes][23] and you can find
by PK related record in DB.

```
<form action="my_action.php">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="bikes[23]"> <br></td>
            <td><input value="Bike 1"> Bike 1<br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="bikes[24]"> <br></td>
            <td><input value="Bike 2"> Bike 2<br></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: you mean that $_POST[bike][23] here is for the checkboxes and the id (23) can be used to get the input for the checked box ?

Comment: I mean $_POST[bikes][23] is the result of submitted form - exactly selected checkboxes. You can take this as array and save values to database. You should also remember about the save unchecked values - also save this value in some way. After that if you show values on the form you should show checkboxes as checked if they were checked in DB and just show readonly inputs close to them(as you wanted).